# Find out why my Android phone is rebooting

Tags: reboot, debug

All of a sudden, my almost 2-year-old Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo starts rebooting at random times.

I did some research, and various forum threads on the Internet recommend different "try this" solutions: Factory-reset the phone, remove apps, remove SD card, etc.

Since I am not a big fan on [shotgun debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_debugging) and I'd rather avoid spending hours to re-install and re-configure everything just to find out that this was *not* the cause of the problem, I'd prefer a more systematical approach.

**Is there a way to find out why my Android phone is rebooting without randomly "trying things"?** For example, are there some log files that I can view which can shed light on this issue?

In case it matters: My phone is non-rooted and (for reasons of warranty) I'd like it to stay that way.

Comment: Try a software instead which will take a complete backup of your phone then do a reset and then restore that backup. Backing up and Restoring will be one click operation. Not promoting but Wondershare MobileGo can help.

Comment: Since you talk about logs, the Android logcat is the first thing that comes to mind. You can either install a terminal emulator on your phone, and then issue `logcat -f <path>` or opt for a solution which requires `adb` on a computer, in which case the appropriate command would be `adb shell logcat -f <path>`. In both cases, `<path>` has to be replaced by the path where you wish to create the log file, compleye with filename and extension (a plain .txt will suffice). Note that this command must run until the reboot, and hence it will tend to produce a file which is quite big.